# Having sharp, pulsating stinging pain in upper left foot.

Tags: running, pain, barefoot

I borrowed the picture from someone else's foot problem that, when I read further, didn't seem to be what I'm going through.

Edit: (>_<) Scratch the picture, because I'm a new user I can't use them. Here's a link to the picture, but you'll have to disregard the OP's "It hurt's right in there somewhere."

[Pain in the top of my foot](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/pain-in-the-top-of-my-foot)

A little background to paint the picture: I'm in the Corps and I LOVE to run... after about 2 months of uncomfortable pain in my right upper leg, near my femoral artery I went to medical. The day before, I'd gone on quite a long run. The following day it was nearly impossible for me to use my right leg... had to lift it into my car just to get in. Medical initially thought it was a hernia, whatever that is... but with some preeeeetty extensive examination of my down stairs mix-up they diagnosed me with a groin strain and pulled muscle near the artery. They put me on light duty for 2 weeks and told me not to run.

I hadn't *really* ran during that time :( but I did do some sloooow jogs after a week in... which brings me to my current problem. I think, because of my leg I was putting too much strain on my opposite foot and after today's jog that I did, now that I'm off of light duty... the pain in my left foot is excruciating. It looks slightly darkened around the area and hurts like a **BLAM** when I press down on it. Trying to figure out what it was on the internet, I had mistakenly rolled my fingers over the extensor digitorum longus tendons outlined in the picture to see if that was where the pain was. I'm pretty sure it's something to do with them... or the bone below it. IDK for certain... that's why I'm throwing this massive explanation out there to you guys.

Oh yes, and it also hurts during the run, when I bend my toes upward to press off from the ground... mainly on the inside, if I force my foot to land on the outside edge it takes away some of the pain. I can't NOT bend my foot to run, because I do the whole "natural" running scene thing, i.e. Vibram Five Fingers, Huarache sandals, etc. Except of course when I have to run in my combat boots. Landing on the heel is so bad for you. :-/

Hope you had time to read on this, and thanks very much to anyone who responds. -Semper Fi!

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is a purely medical question. It's not even really a question, just a request for diagnosis. Sorry. For more on why medical questions don't belong here, see this [meta](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/70/medical-questions) question, or [this one](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/133/what-should-main-fn-faq-say-about-health-medicine-questions-answers).

Comment: This question is "too medical".

Comment: Sorry about that. I've never used this site. I simply asked, because I saw a similar medical question within here as it was linked via Google.

Comment: The other question was specifically if it was normal to have pain in that area of the foot after switching from normal shoes to Vibrams. We're just trying to avoid the liability of giving medical specific diagnosis or advice. We gladly welcome your input on the site though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sarge says, this is for a doctor to diagnose properly.

I had something similar - or rather with the same symtoms as I understand you - 3-4 years ago as I first started to run for races: [stress fracture foot](http://stressfracturefoot.org/). Basically, this is very small stress induced fractures in the bones of the foot - though it can be in any bone in the body in theory. Very often a result of too much running :-) Only you doc can tell you for sure with an MR scanning or similar.

Ohh, and the bad news is that the only real solution is to stop running for an extended period. In my case 4-5 months after which I could start again... slowly, ever so slowly...

Comment: Thanks for the response: I've scheduled an appointment with the Doc for tomorrow morning. I really hope I won't have to wait 4-5 months for this problem to be solved... Running is like feeling freedom to me.

Answer (score 0):

For this one, consult a doctor. Why would you trust the opinion of some random person on the internet vs a medical professional who can physically examine your foot.

We see this on the Ultra list (a mailing list filled with ultra runners) all the time. The general response is go find a good doctor who has a clue about running.

1. Are you sure you just haven't pulled your laces too tight?
2. You have probably returned to running too early and have been favouring the injury leading to problems elsewhere.

Comment: Also, thanks to you for the reply. Don't have any laces on my running gear, though... I imagine you're right about me trying to get back to running too soon, but I did so trusting the Doc's previous suggestion to stay off my leg for two weeks. Guess it was worse than she thought. I'll find out after my appointment tomorrow... Hopefully it won't take long to heal. Cheers!