# Making stamina for running

Tags: running, running-training-plan

It's been 6-7 months since I am trying to make stamina to run, but I can only run for 1 min and rest I walk. I force myself by my ankle hurts. What is the exercise I should do to make stamina? I been told by Nike people that I have wide foot. Don't know if that account for the pain in my ankle. How can I focus when I am on tredmill that I don't focus on time, because my mind also play with me when it sees 1 min is done.

Comment: What is your height and weight? the "nike people", did they also diagnose your gait to have some pronation?

Comment: @OmarAsifShaikh what's probation? I m 5.9 and 79kg

Comment: After seeing a few of your posts, are these questions even serious?

Comment: @tannman357 yes mate, I been working out a lot and I don't see anything change.

Comment: What area are you located in? I think it would be a good idea for you to find someone local to help you out.

Comment: @tannman357 like you mentioned, your trainer is putting you at risk in last post. So I wouldn't trust them.

Comment: @nofel terribly sorry,  its called pronation. Its very common.

Comment: Only if they are no good

Comment: Guide for Safe Running: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/938/7706    Guide for Running Shoes: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/113/7706   strengthening the Ankle: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/1225/7706

Comment: @tannman357 it's waste of money, I would rather take help from bodybuilding.com , my question remain same on how to increase stamina of running, I been told 170 heartbeat per min would be effective for me. When they did my assement

Comment: My previous comment has PF questions that may solve your problem, if still have doubts, drop in a comment!

Comment: AHAHHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA

Comment: At what speed do you run and have you considered running more slowly? Starting slow can be very beneficial: because you can keep it up much longer you'll be more motivated and you'll burn more calories in the total run. Also the risk on injuries will be reduced. And once you got the hang of it, you can always increase your speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best and easiest beginners running plan is [Couch to 5k](http://www.c25k.com/) (or more commonly Couch25k).

Its a well tested plan for taking you from no running at all to running a continuous 5 kilometers (or about 3 mile). There are numerous official and unofficial apps for your phone that help you keep pace with the plan.

If you are looking at building running stamina, it is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

**Running and Ankle Pain**

- Diagnosis - You really should have your ankle pain diagnosed by your doctor so you know what the problem is and how to correct it.
- Alternatives to running on a treadmill - You said on another question that you are learning to swim so you have access to a pool.  Since your ankle hurts when on the treadmill, you may want to try [running in the pool.](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6894/what-is-the-a-proper-way-to-pool-run)
  You can get a good cardio workout in the pool without having to bear weight on your foot.

  You can do intervals where you alternate moving slowly (walking), and moving fast (running). When you get tired running, walk until you recover and then try running again.  Alternate walk, run, walk, run etc. For a specific progression the [Couch to 5K program](http://www.c25k.com/podcasts.htm) is a good way to go.  You listen to the program and walk and run according to the program.

  Cycling or a stationary cycle may also be easier on your ankle.

**Motivation**

As for motivation, set goals.  A good goal gives a specific action and a specific time frame.

- "I will run 5, one minute intervals today." - This is a process goal saying what you will do in order to reach a specific outcome.
- "In 9 weeks I will be able to run 30 minutes without stopping." - This is an outcome goal.  It states what you want to be able to achieve within a given time frame.

  Make your goals realistic so that you can feel good about accomplishing your goal.  Making too difficult a goal can result in failure.  Once you have met an easy goal, gradually increase the difficulty.

  Keep a log of your process and plot it on a graph to see your improvement.  Seeing how far you have come is good motivation.